# Angular CLI - angular 5.2.0 with ng-boostrap is not working

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-cli, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to setup angular application with [angular cli](https://cli.angular.io/) and there is a new [ng-boostrap module](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started) specifically for angular application

```
ng new angular-cli-bootstrap-test
cd angular-cli-bootstrap-test

npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
ng serve
```

and adding few configurations for ng-boostrap, **app.module.ts**:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  model = {
    left: true,
    middle: false,
    right: false
  };
}
```

**app.component.html**:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle">
  <label class="btn-primary" ngbButtonLabel>
    <input type="checkbox" ngbButton [(ngModel)]="model.left"> Left (pre-checked)
  </label>
  <label class="btn-primary" ngbButtonLabel>
    <input type="checkbox" ngbButton [(ngModel)]="model.middle"> Middle
  </label>
  <label class="btn-primary" ngbButtonLabel>
    <input type="checkbox" ngbButton [(ngModel)]="model.right"> Right
  </label>
</div>
<hr>
<pre>{{model | json}}</pre>
```

Sorry if I missed something, everything is being displayed without any errors but without bootstrap styles, maybe I am missing something?

page source form browser:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularCliBootstrapTest</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post the output HTML of the app/page. Is Bootstrap css being loaded there?

Comment: doesn't seems to be loaded... but if you lookup `ng-boostrap` it says:
`Should I add bootstrap.js or bootstrap.min.js to my project?

No, the goal of ng-bootstrap is to completely replace JavaScript implementation for components. Nor should you include other dependencies like jQuery or popper.js. It is not necessary and might interfere with ng-bootstrap code.`

Comment: css is not the same as js.

Comment: @WebDevBooster do really think I don't know the difference between css and js? check the manual, does it says something about css?

Comment: If you know the difference, then posting your previous comment wouldn't have made any sense whatsoever.

Comment: @Evilguy The first comment says that you forgot to load the bootstrap **CSS** (and it's right). You justify not loading the bootstrap CSS by quoting documentation saying "Should I add bootstrap.**js** or bootstrap.min.**js** to my project? No". JS != CSS. You must not load the bootstrap **JS**. But you must load the bootstrap **CSS**.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks for justifying, I understand that, it solved the problem by adding css, but the thing is I was following the document where was no word about css!

Comment: can anyone create a tag for me please `ng-bootstrap` for current question.

Comment: @Evilguy the tag already exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding css solved my problem, which is not defined in [ng-boostrap manual](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularCliBootstrapTest</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```